# What can cause Rails to run migrations every time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, rails-migrations

What can cause Rails to run migrations every time?

I am deploying to a qa environment and migrations run everytime as if rails is setting up the entire database again.

here is my `config/environments/qa.rb`

```
Backend::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  config.assets.compile = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Raise exception on mass assignment protection for Active Record models
  config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  # ActionMailer Config
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3002' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # change to true to allow email to be sent during development
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"


end
```

Edit: Rails 4.0 and 3.2 - `rake db:migrate` runs all migrations every time.

Edit: deploying with capistrano: `cap qa deploy`

Comment: It's happening on Rails 4.0 and 3.2.

Comment: how are you deploying?

Comment: with capistrano: `cap qa deploy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dope, I am so careless. I was using sqlite3. This meant that capistrano would create a new release and a new database everytime. This can be solved by linking to the database file.

I am electing to create a database hosted on AWS.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you have **migrate** task in your Capistrano deploy file.

Check in **config/deploy.rb** if there is some variation of **migrate** (it could be "**deploy:migrate**" or full rake task).

Comment: Capistrano is set to do migrations, but doesn't rails not run them if the database is setup? If I do rake db:setup, rails is still running full migrations the next time I deploy.

Comment: Then, check path of your database in config/database.yml. It could be because your database path (for relevant environment, it should be Production) is in directory: current?